# What project type and approach is recommended for reusable windows?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, resourcedictionary

I manage a suite of tools that operate on the same basic data structures and have several opportunities for reuse. 
Typical examples include

- A help->about dialog with some artistic branding and general user support info.
- Data browsing dialogs.
- Rich Error / Debug detail windows that report on the common data structures. (these are windows, not controls)

How do I best go about creating common resources like this for many click-once apps within a single VS2010 solution?
Do I start them out as user control libraries or regular class libraries?
Do I start creating them within a new WPF application, then removing the app.xaml/application handling? Effectively "morphing" them into class libraries? Like described here:
[How to convert WPF project so it can be used as a class library by a separate exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805387)