# Create own toolbox element in VS 2012 .Net-Framework 4 (c#)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

is there any possibility to create your own button as toolbox element (for other projects) in Visual Studio 2012 (version 11.0.50727.1)?

I just need a button (like the button from iTunes) for another project. (Tutorials are also welcome).

WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this ended up being Wpf, I believe the easist way to go would be to create a `WpfControlLibrary` that is used for `UserControls` that way it would be easier for you to customize the look and feel of your Button. It can also be added to your ToolBox by right clicking on your ToolBox and Selecting `Choose Items` then Select `WpfComponents` and Browse to your Dll.

See these Links:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/bb514641.aspx
2. [What is the difference between a User Control Library and a Custom Control Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807703/what-is-the-difference-between-a-user-control-library-and-a-custom-control-libra)
3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx

Comment: Do u have a simple sample?
Cause I don't know what to do when OnPaint() is called.

Comment: You need to ignore the first part of my answer that pertained to Winforms, in fact I will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom control for your button and compile it into a separate dll. Then add this control from this dll to the toolbox.

See for example here: http://dhavalupadhyaya.wordpress.com/2008/07/20/how-to-add-custom-control-in-visual-studio-toolbox/

Comment: Seems to be outdated. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are talking about a WPF button. If it's for one extra project, you are perhaps best off creating a button style in a seperate XAML resource file and reusing that file in the second project. If you need to create a reusable control to the extent that you need a button for it in the VS toolbox, then see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712573.aspx

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2010 & 2012 installed. Downloaded both SDKs but the "WPF Toolbox Control"-Template isn't installed.

Any solutions?
Thnx :)